# If $E = KL$, then $\operatorname{Aut}(E/L)\simeq\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

$\newcommand{\Gal}{\operatorname{Gal}}$ My question arose from [my previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4257854/668308). I want to say $\Gal(\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]{p},\eta)/\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]{p}))\simeq \Gal(\Bbb Q(\eta)/\Bbb Q)$ so that the sequence splits. So in general situation, what is a sufficient condition to be:

> If $E =KL$ is a composite field and field extension of $F$, then $\operatorname{Aut}(E/K)\simeq\operatorname{Aut}(L/F)$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer by user8268 : $[E:K] = [L:F]$.

Comment: that would be true under the condition that $K\otimes_FL$ is a field (which is then $E$), or equivalently if $[E:K]=[L:F]$ (if the extensions are finite)

Comment: @user8268 Why is that?

Comment: A small remark to the title. $F$ comes from nowhere, if we only know $E=KL$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde but in the main post, I indicated $F$ is a base field of $E$

Comment: For this reason it was a remark concerning the title (which one reads first - and sometimes only... :) )

Comment: the same Galois groups certainly imply the same degrees; in the other direction, every $F$-automorphism of $L$ lifts canonically to a $K$-automorphism of $K\otimes_FL$

Comment: @user8268 Thanks. Is that an if and only if statement?

Comment: yes - it's enough to think about the degrees of the extensions, orders of groups, and that lifting off automorphisms